# Get more signal layers in Altium?

Tags: altium

I am trying to run a test that requires a board to have 57 signal layers, however in the layer stack manager, I am unable to get more than 32 layers.  Signal is grayed out when I go to add another layer. Is there a way to add more layers or is 32 the max?

I am using version 20.0.13

EDIT: The test is to see if the Dragonfly (3D PCB printer) can actually do it because 57 is stated as it's max but good to know that 32 is indeed the max.

Comment: I for one would like to know why you think you need 57 signal layers. I'm sure you don't (and not even close either).

Comment: 12 layers is a lotta layers, let alone 57.

Comment: 57 is an odd number, and it's an odd number.  Why not 58?  I'd love to see the end product.

Comment: Have to agree.   If you're working somewhere that 57 layer PCB's are required, you shouldn't be using Altium.    Perhaps you really don't need 57 layers???    And yes, 32 is the max.

Comment: The 57 layers probably includes the insulation layers in the count rather than being the number of copper layers as in Altium.  That would make the 32 copper layers in Altium sufficient to test the Dragonfly.

Comment: @Kyle B Just out of curiosity, what WOULD you be using in case you'd need to work on 57 layer board? Some custom software, or are there packages out there that can handle such a task?

Comment: Export all 32 layers as GERBER files (or whatever format the printer needs), delete the 30 inner layers (keeping top and bottom as reference) and add layers 33 to 57. Export those as more GERBERs.

Comment: @AnthropomorphousDodecahedron    I really should better say....   My meaning was something like "Altium is professional software, but it's "low end"  professional software".  I use Altium, use it all the time.  I think it's perfect for my field.  Just the right combination of simplicity and power.   Something higher end like PADS would handle more layers.   I meant "If OP really has a 57 layer design, either they must already be in a company that is using something far more powerful than Altium or the requirement for 57 layers is a misunderstanding of 'how to layout PCBs' "

Comment: @BrianDrummond    While in theory that would definitely work, I think it's impractical.  You'd lose all your netlist connections between the two designs.  I'd think a '57 layer design' would be outrageously complex and maintaining track of the connections impossible.

Comment: Elizabeth --- I just experimented with Altium layer stack manager.   While it's true it's limiting the number of 'signal layers' to 32, I found you can ALSO define 32 plane layers.  So it seems you can get 64 copper layers.  If you're doing a 57-layer design, a large number of your layers MUST be plane layers, yes?     If so, you may be OK using Altium

Comment: @Kyle ... true in general, but if this is a test piece it may be a usable solution, if the circuit can be designed with this in mind (structured as 2 independent netlists)

Comment: @KyleB I find it odd that you state that you should use something 'far more powerfull than Altium'. I can only think of two packages that could be considered 'more powerfull', and that would be Mentor Xpedition, and Cadence Allegro? What features would you find in a package that is 'far more powerfully' that Altium lacks?

Answer (score -2):

I suspect you want many many layers, so you can easily route. Typically people use VIAS to switch layers to jump over other traces.

Or you may want many many layers to keep traces well apart, to minimize crosstalk.

However, if signal fidelity is your goal, then using Ground Planes is the better approach.

A guy names Howard Johnson (had website) explained the crosstalk between traces will drop as 1/Distance^3, if the traces are OVER A PLANE.

Are planes a possibility?

Comment: The question is about generating a test file for a 3D printer that claims to be able to do 57 layers.  There's no requirements except "traces on  more than 32 layers."

Comment: Not to mention there are a lot of cases where people do actually use such high layer count boards. I've known a few people working on actual boards with layercounts in the 50's (EG, routing boards with 4 ASICs with each 256 56 GBit/s PAM4 trancievers)